# Any way to convert Autohotkey into Apple Script?

Tags: applescript, autohotkey

Here is my code:

```
Same Mouse Click:
f2::
MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
ControlClick, x%xpos% y%ypos%, Window1
ControlClick, x%xpos% y%ypos%, Window2
return
```

It should make a Mouse click on two different windows when pressing f2.

Apple Script seems rather complicated are there any converters to run Hotkey Scripts on a Mac?

Or has anyone a simple solution to this?´

Comment: AHK can't work on anything but Windows. Sure it may be possible to accomplish this on a Mac, but for that you'll need to know both of the languages well. For example you'd need to know what ControlClick actually is. You can check the C++ from the AHK source code for what actually happens when you use ControlClick.

Comment: Maybe try `pyautogui`